# Android RunTimeException can't instantiate class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having some problem when trying to load data from SQLite into tableLayout.

DataBaseAdapter.java

```
protected static final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";
private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}

public DatabaseAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        Log.e(TAG, "Database Created");
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.e(TAG, "Database Open");
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return mDb;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat
                                                // window
// destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "schoolAssignment";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private final Context mContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    // If database not exists copy it from the assets
    Log.e(TAG, "CreateDataBase()");
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!mDataBaseExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try {
            // Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}

// Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Database
// Name
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    Log.e("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}

// Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}

// Open the database, so we can query it
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Log.v("mPath", mPath);
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    // mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
    // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDataBase != null;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Exercise.java

```
TableLayout table_layout;

private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public Exercise(SQLiteDatabase mDb) {
    this.mDb = mDb;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);
    table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
    BuildTable();
}

private void BuildTable() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM exercise";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int rows = mCur.getCount();
                    int cols = mCur.getColumnCount();
                    // outer for loop
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                        // inner for loop
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tv.setTextSize(18);
                            tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                            tv.setText(mCur.getString(j));
                            row.addView(tv);

                        }
                        table_layout.addView(row);
                    }
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
```

However, I am getting the error message as the LogCat:

```
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{edu.nyp.project/edu.nyp.project.Exercise}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class edu.nyp.project.Exercise; no empty constructor
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class edu.nyp.project.Exercise; no empty constructor
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
07-29 22:51:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    ... 11 more
07-29 22:51:45.088: I/Process(32638): Sending signal. PID: 32638 SIG: 9
```

I did put the database I created from SQLite Database Browser into assets folder of the current project. I not sure why the error message telling me it cant find the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any exception related to sqlite, maybe you should try to add an empty constructor to Exercise as asked in the log, and don't forget to set mDb in this empty constructor

Comment: @ex0ns But do you have any ideas? Cause I am totally lost

Comment: @ex0ns Because when I set an empty constructor in Exercise class, the error message turns to NullPointerException

Comment: If you add constructor with arguments, default-no args constructor wont be available. Hence any attempt to create an instance using no-args will fail. He it looks like ,Android itself is trying to create instance of this class reflectively without args, so it is not able to instantiate , since it is not available. You can try providing new no args constructor, and initialize your sqlLite db inside this constructor to avoid null pointer ( just initialize mDB inside empty constructor).

Comment: @Jimmy Would you mind to provide me some example?

Comment: add some thing like this,  `public Exercise() {
    this.mDb = new DatabaseAdabpter(this).open();
}`   . Just intialize mDb inside this constructor somehow . I doubt the above initialization runs without error thought.

Comment: It solved the problem but it gives me another error message which is unable to open the database. Why is it so?

Comment: because as I mentioned earlies, thats probably not the right way to open your database. Refer to your DatabaseAdapter code to open the sql lite db properly.

Comment: @Jimmy Not the right way to open the database as in? Sorry I am really new to this and did not have much knowledge. Would you mind to explain further?

Comment: Where are you instanciating your Exercise object ?

Comment: @Pierre These are all the codes I have. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your Exercice object extending another object ? Because I don't understand why you have a onCreate method in your Exercice object if it isn't an `Activity`

Comment: in your no args constructor, try this , `this.mDB= new DataBaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();` . And it seems like your Exercise class is actually an activity. If so, its not wise to get your DML/DDL in here. Create another layer for DDl/DML, and you dont have to deal with these crazy problem

Comment: @Pierre I thought onCreate is something like OnPageLoad in c#? I wanted the table to load when I transfer from ome activity to this.

Answer (score 3):

If you add constructor with arguments, default-no args constructor wont be available. Hence any attempt to create an instance using no-args constructor will fail. Here, it looks like ,Android itself is trying to create instance of this class reflectively using no-args, but since no-args constructor is not available, it is not able to instantiate new object of Exercise class. You can try providing new no args constructor, and initialize your sqlLite db inside this constructor to avoid null pointer ( just initialize mDB inside empty constructor).
something like,

```
public Exercise() {    
     this.mDb =  new DataBaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();  
}
```

. The initialization of mDb depends upon what you are trying to get. It could be readable databse, writable database or so forth.  You just need to initialize the mDb here to get your code working. 
If I were you, I would create another class that this Exercise class can use and use SQL related any features on that new class (as DAO layer) rather than using SQLdatabase in Exercise class ( assumption is that your Exercise class in extending Activty class as of now).

Comment: But still, it is throwing me null pointer exception error message. I check the database in DDMS when running the apps but the folder is empty. But when I go into the assets folder, the database is inside. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: can you update the stack trace? and also update the code with class definition as well. Need to see what classes are extended by classes.